# VB how to input string Convert to characters upper and Lower

Tags: vb.net

in VB how i can input string  Convert to characters upper and Lower as input ' hello'
but output like 'HeLlO'
my code thiis

```
  Sub ConvertCase()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim inputVal As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim out As String = Label1.Text
        Do While i > inputVal.Length()
            If inputVal.Length() Mod 2 = 0 Then
                out = inputVal.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper
            End If
            If inputVal.Length() Mod 2 <> 0 Then
                out = inputVal.Substring(1).ToLower
            End If
            Loop
        Label1.Text &= out
    End Sub
```

i don't know what's wrong ><
thanks

Comment: Your substring values are both wrong

Comment: i know -_- this a try
can you help me ?please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just needed to append to out

```
out &= ...
```

And the substring wasn't done properly.

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To inputVal.Length - 1
        If (i Mod 2) = 0 Then
            out &= Char.ToUpper(inputVal(i))
        Else
            out &= Char.ToLower(inputVal(i))
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

For LINQ lovers:

```
Label1.Text = New String(TextBox1.Text.Select(Function(c, i) If(i Mod 2 = 0, Char.ToUpper(c), Char.ToLower(c))).ToArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
Dim str As String = "hello"
Dim strlength As Integer = str.Length
Dim ii As Integer = 0
Dim output As String = ""
   For Each c As Char In str
     If ii Mod 2 = 0 Then
         output += c.ToString.ToUpper
     Else
         output += c.ToString.ToLower
     End If
     ii += 1
    Next
MsgBox(output)
```